# Cant figure out slash commands in discord.py 2.0

Tags: discord.py, python-asyncio, python-3.10, pycord

I am trying to upgrade a outdated python3 discord bot to the new discord.py 2.0 with slash commands and some more async and await in the cog setup. But I just cant figure out how the slash commands work and how I setup cogs. Can someone show some code examples of the main.py file and a example of one cog file.

Some people on youtube seems to be using "py-cord". I did try py-cord but I got problems when I wanted to use cogs, but the slash commands worked. I followed another tutorial on how to use cogs in discord.py 2.0 and I got it working but then I could not figure out how to use slash commands in that.

Comment: Don't use tutorials on YouTube, they're all outdated and teach bad code. Just read the docs & look at the official examples... App commands example: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/app_commands/basic.py Migration guide for async cogs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#command-extension-changes

Answer (score 0):

You can find an up-to-date example in the pycord docs: [pycord cogs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html)